# time clock with buttons in python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, stopwatch

I'm trying to program a little time clock to track my worktime. Its a very simple program which calculates the difference of two datetime variables.

I have the following problem:
When I press the stop button the program prints the right time. But I want to print the right time and then reset the timer. But this won't work because I can't change the variable "startzeit". Is there any way I can make this work like a real watch?

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime

startzeit = datetime.datetime.today()
stoppzeit = datetime.datetime.today()
date = datetime.date.today()


def start():
    global startzeit
    startzeit = datetime.datetime.today()


def stopp():
        stoppzeit = datetime.datetime.today()
        diff = stoppzeit-startzeit
        print(date, ":", diff)


fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Stechuhr ")
fenster.geometry("170x40")

Start = Button(fenster, text="Start", command=start)
Start.place(x=10, y=10, width=70, height=20)

Stop = Button(fenster, text="Stop", command=stopp)
Stop.place(x=90, y=10, width=70, height=20)

mainloop()
```

Comment: 1) The global `stoppzeit` is not necessary; 2) add `global startzeit` and assign it the value of `stoppzeit` after `print(...)` inside `stopp()`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me already. But what you can do is:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime

global startzeit

startzeit = datetime.datetime.today()
stoppzeit = datetime.datetime.today()
date = datetime.date.today()


def start():
    global startzeit
    startzeit = datetime.datetime.today()


def stopp():
        global startzeit
        stoppzeit = datetime.datetime.today()
        diff = stoppzeit-startzeit
        diff = date ,":",diff
        label2.config(text=diff)
        print(diff)
        startzeit = stoppzeit


fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Stechuhr ")
fenster.geometry("210x80")

label1 = Label(text="Zeit", padx=10, pady=5)
label1.place(x=10, y=5, width=70, height=20)

label2 = Label(text="Timediff", padx=10, pady=5)
label2.place(x=10, y=25, width=190, height=20)

Start = Button(fenster, text="Start", command=start)
Start.place(x=10, y=45, width=70, height=20)

Stop = Button(fenster, text="Stop", command=stopp)
Stop.place(x=90, y=45, width=70, height=20)

mainloop()
```

What I did is: I made the global declaration at the beginning and in every function that used the global declaration. This is to tell the function that it should use the global version of the variable startzeit.

Edit:
I added `startzeit = stoppzeit` and other stuff to see the result in the window. (Sorry cannot comment atm)

Comment: But your code did not reset `startzeit` inside `stopp()`.

Comment: @acw1668 But we don't need to since ```start()``` overwrites the variable because of the global declaration and  ```stopp()``` isn't using the local variable anymore.

Comment: hi thanks for your answers! Is there maybe a way to say: if the stopp is pressed a second time it prints: 0

Comment: @Hank Does the code work for you? And to your 2nd question, yes there is: Make a global counter. Let it count up if stop is pressed and make an if case that prints 0 when the count is over 1. And reset the counter in the start function.